# How to define a base class?

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance

I am getting a an error called C2504: 'MyCourse' : base class undefined

I have 3 classes, but all of them need to share some information with each other :

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyStudent : public MyCourse {
   public :
     vector<double> assignScores;
     vector<double> testScores;
     string getName();
     string getAssignName();
     string getTestName();
     int getAssignScale();
     int getTestScale();
     void calcAssignPercentage();
     void calcTestPercentage();
     void addAssignScore(double sc);
     void addTestScore(double sc);
     void toStringDisplay();
};

class MyCourse : public MyStudent {
public:
    string courseName;
    vector <MyStudent> allStudents;
    void addStudent();
    void toStringDisplay();
    void addAssignAll();
    void addTestAll();
};



class MyDriver1 : public MyCourse, public MyStudent
{
public :
    void student();
    void assignment();
    void test();
    void show();
    void help();
    void quit();
};
```

How can I have a base class when each of them extends to another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class MyStudent : public MyCourse {`

`class MyCourse : public MyStudent {`

`class MyDriver1 : public MyCourse, public MyStudent`

This is bad practice.

A base class first of all, should define COMMON functionality and variables which are to be inherited by child classes.  It shouldn't be set up like the above where classes are all inheriting from each other.

Take a step back from all three classes, ask yourself, what things in common do all of these classes need?

A `MyStudent` should not extend a `MyCourse` and a `MyCourse` should not extend a `MyStudent`.

A `MyStudent` should have a declaration of a `MyCourse` object somewhere inside it if you wish to store course information from a student

Comment: As it could been seen from my codes, I am a beginner ... I extended the classes just because I needed to excess data. I understand my mistake of disorganization of my classes.

Comment: I agree with you, I understand it know, I just do not know how to declare an object of MyCourse inside the MyStudent class so I could be able to store the information about a student. Can you give me a code sample of how to accomplish that without messing with extensions in an incorrect way

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular reference in your inheritance hierarchy. This is not allowed in C++, and it doesn't make sense anyway. Inheritance is used to model "is-a" relationships. If `B` extends `A`, then a `B` is a more specific example of an `A`. In that case, how could an `A` also be a more specific example of an `A`?

You need to rethink what you are actually trying to model here, and design your class hierarchy accordingly. A student is *not* a course, and a course is *not* a student. Inheritance is not the appropriate tool to model this relationship.

A course *contains* a list of enrolled students. The correct way to model this is called [composition](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/): your course class should contain some sort of list of students.

Comment: thanks for clarifying everything. I need to organize my voids around, so the relationships could work out